# Pheatmap annotation colors edit size

Tags: r, pheatmap

Pheatmap `library(pheatmap)` takes annotation_colors to add the header ID colors on the top of each heatmap column.

I want to control and edit the size of the column header (boxes red and blue).

Below is what I have done so far.

```
library(pheatmap)   
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame( matrix(sample(30), ncol = 5))
colnames(df)<-LETTERS[1:5]
subj<-c("P1", "P2","P3", "T1", "T2","T3")
rownames(df)<-subj
aka2 = data.frame(ID = factor(rep(c("Pat","Trea"), each=3)))
rownames(aka2)<-subj
aka3 = list(ID = c(Pat = "red", Trea="blue"))
pheatmap(t(scale(df)),
         annotation_col = aka2, 
         annotation_colors = aka3[1],
         annotation_legend = FALSE,
         gaps_col =  3,
         show_colnames = T, show_rownames = T, cluster_rows = F, 
         cluster_cols = F, legend = TRUE, 
         clustering_distance_rows = "euclidean", border_color = FALSE)
```

Comment: `fontsize` argument?

Comment: You can also pass arguments for `fontsize_row` and `fontsize_col`

Comment: Yes but `fontsize` also enlarges the characters within the graph, I am interested in editing only the header coloured boxes.